# How to add drop down menu for store change

Tags: magento-2.1, multistore

I want to add a store change URL in the header nearby sign in (multi-store).

eg: the main website shows multi-store links

Comment: do you want static links with drop down  or with session storage ?

Comment: yes. the multi-store name never changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 ) **Create Store and Store View**

```
Go to Admin > Stores > All Stores
```

**Create Store** Fill all details > Website / Name / Category

**Create store View** Select store/name/code/status must be enabled / set order

**Now run php bin/magento indexer:reindex**

Your stores drop down can be seen in footer by default

2 ) **Extend your Store Switcher  under this path** for making any changes

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Store/templates/switch/stores.phtml
```

3 ) **Move in header using XML**

`app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" before="header.links" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>

        </referenceContainer>
```

In case you do not extend the module the use this code to move it in header

```
<move element="store_switcher" destination="header.panel" before="header.links" />
```

This should help you out, let me know if any problem

Thanks

Comment: Am a newbie in Magento, Store Switcher? which way create this one

Comment: Please wait few minutes , will back to you soon and help you out

Comment: Check updated answer , this is on default luma theme . Create stores then extend your file and move to header .

Comment: 1 ) Create Store and Store View

Go to Admin > Stores > All Stores
Create Store Fill all details > Website / Name / Category

Create store View Select store/name/code/status must be enabled / set order

Now run php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Your stores drop down can be seen in footer by default

2 ) Extend your Store Switcher under this path for making any changes

app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Store/templates/switch/stores.phtml

could not found Magento_store or any other store name

Answer (score 0):

For this you just have to create multiple store in admin in a single website.

```
Goto Admin -> Stores -> All Stores
```

and create store view for multiple stores. It will show dropdown in frontend with all store option.