# Magento 2: I want to Display a Store switcher drop down in Top Header

Tags: magento2, multistore, store-switcher

I'm trying to make a drop-down for a **store** not store views on the top header.

I had searched more and more, but unfortunately always getting the store views solutions.

I had created an on `Magento_Store/templates/switch/stores.phtml`  and declared the `stores.phtml` on the `Magento_Theme/block/default.xml` Still nothing comes.

Anyone help me to set a drop-down for switching the stores.

Comment: Please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183275/how-to-add-drop-down-menu-for-store-change

Comment: @MuhammadHasham i checked that already that not works. :(

Comment: Just to check you have different stores on same website? Unmodified store switcher will only work in that scenario.